# SSRS Time Format

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm pulling a time that is seconds from midnight (example: `55800`). This is supposed to be `3:30pm` `(55800/3600) = 15.50` which is `1530` in military time, which is `3:30pm`.

I can probably figure out how to do this in straight SQL but the query itself is a `function` so the format I need I believe is different. What would be the correct syntax in `SSRS` to make that time `3:30 PM`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _the query itself is a function_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat quick and crude way of handling this is in an expression:

```
Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Second, Fields!Seconds.Value, CDate("1970-01-01")), "hh:mm tt")
```

Breaking it down, it doesn't matter what date you choose since you are only concerned with the *time* value. You also don't need to set the time to midnight as it'll default to midnight.

The expression adds your seconds from midnight using `DateAdd`. The result of this would look something like:

> 1970-01-01 15:30:00

Finally, `Format` with the custom format string `hh:mm tt` will take the time part of the *datetime* value. `tt` specifies whether AM/PM is included in the final formatted output.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much it works perfect. I didn't even have to do the additional formatting.

Comment: You're most welcome. When I get a chance, I will _try_ and add custom code you could use in the report to save repeating this format expression wherever it's needed.